# How to translate XPage application "on the fly"?

Tags: xpages

On IBM's website, I found [a nice tutorial about localization of XPage applications](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/UsingLocalizationOptions.htm).  If you look in the comments, you'll see I added a couple before figuring out how to make it work.
   For the fun of it, change the language option to French, and take a look at my comments below.  My comments were translated!  Not super well, but I was able to correct the French text, without changing the original English text.  Based on the French, I don't believe the original wiki page was translated, either.

With localization, you can change the properties files, reimport them, etc... but what about the comments or text entered by users?  Does anyone know how IBM did this?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would need to go through some translation service. If you can post the link of the IBM site where you are seeing this happening I can see if I can get more details.

Comment: How did you "change the language option to French"?

Comment: @Simon - so, you think IBM translated my comments on the above page within seconds after I posted them?  Or, perhaps, they have some newer version of "Babelfish" or whatever.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Per - in the top right corner of the page, you'll see a drop down list of languages.  Sadly, Danish isn't one of them, but you can try any of the languages you may know there to see how it works.

Comment: Google Translate has a REST API that you can shoot the comments at but there is a cost involved - https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/using_rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Doc!  In my work group, we have offically certified translators who work with English, French, Spanish, Russian, Chinese and Arabic.  They'll be able to translate all the programmatic terms, and we'll look into the Google API if we need to modify a lot of user entered text in the applications I'm building.

Answer (score 4):

Translations on the IBM wikis are machine translations that use n.Fluent from IBM Research for real-time translation. See [the wiki help for details](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/wiki_help#Translating+a+page) and [the IBM developerWorks group for n.Fluent](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=c7f41400-4eb9-477c-b6fb-042466407259) for more info.